# How can I echo each item in my PHP array rather than just the last?

Tags: php

I have an array in PHP (it has to be PHP for somewhat complicated reasons that go beyond the scope of this post):

```
<?php
$arr = array(Div1, Div2);
foreach ($arr as $value) {
print_r($value);
}
?>
```

I then have some Jquery that I'm attempting to use to hide every element that has a class in that array.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("."+"<?php echo $value; ?>").hide();
});
</script>
```

However, this only hides elements whose class is equivalent to the last item in the array. In other words, only items whose class is `Div2` hide. How can I make this apply to each item in the array?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson extracts from it, yes (except the array uses words other than `Div1` & `Div2`

Comment: if you know the value, you could just avoid printing it?

Comment: So you want to include the JS inside the foreach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can take the php array and use it in javascript. the easiest way is to use json:

```
<?php
  $arr = array('Div1', 'Div2');
?>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var arr = <?=json_encode($arr);?>;
    arr.forEach((className)=>$("."+className).hide());
  });
</script>
```

or you can join the array and let jquery iterate over it:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var arr = <?=json_encode($arr);?>;
    $('.'+arr.join(', .')).hide();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: The first suggestion is EXACTLY what I needed. Thank you so much! I'll accept the answer as soon as it allows me to do so.

Comment: @Snoops you're welcome. If you have any further questions on this, feel free to ask and I will add some more explanations.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I edited the post and now it's fixed. Can we clean up the comments?

Answer (score 1):

after the `foreach` loop finishes, `$value` is still bound to the last value of your `$arr`. either somehow include the js-output into the loop or loop through the array again in your js-php-loop

Comment: Thanks for the response :) I figured that, but how would I loop through the array again?  As a long shot, I tried `$(document).ready(function(){
$("."+"<?php $arr = array(Div1, Div2);
foreach ($arr as $value) {echo $value;} ?>").hide();
});`  but, as expected, it didn't work.

Comment: see the answer from enstage

Answer (score 1):

Replace that JS line with this, it will work as long as `$arr` is in scope wherever the JS code is (which it should be based on your question).

```
<?php
foreach($arr as $value) {
    echo '$("' . '.' . $value . '").hide();';
}
?>
```

You were previously just looping over the array and not doing anything with the values (other than using `print_r()` on them). Therefore when you reached the code in your second snippet, only the last value of `$value` was usable.

Comment: A cleaner (and more readable) concatenation: `echo "$('.$value').hide();";`. In my opinion, anyway. :-)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson second dot missing, {} unnecessary ;o)

Comment: @Jakumi I usually always wrap variables in {} just to make it more clear that it is a PHP variable (and less mistakes are made if the string changes). However, I did actually remove them when I saw your comment. :-)

Comment: you should never use the value of php variables in javascript without consider the change of the context! It's important for security and safety proposes.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson still missing the dot after `$value` though ^^

Comment: @Jakumi No it isn't. It's all within double quotes. [Here's a demo](https://3v4l.org/6mU7V)

Comment: @Enstage  Thank you for taking the time to help me! This is a great suggestion; Joshua K's answer above is more along the lines of what I actually need, because I want to be able to use the variable multiple times within my Javascript

Comment: @MagnusEriksson you're right, shame on me. I never embed php vars though. always makes me feel dirty.

Comment: @Jakumi That's because it _is_ a dirty practice. :-p

Answer (score 0):

Kindly Replace it with the Below code and give a test.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
<?php
$arr = array(Div1, Div2);
foreach ($arr as $value) {
echo '$("."+"'.$value.').hide();';
}
?>
});
</script>
```

Comment: you should never use the value of php variables in javascript without consider the change of the context! It's important for security and safety proposes.

Comment: He needs similar thing. So he can modify it like $div = '$("."+"'.$value.').hide();';
 and now he can echo $div there or Can use it only for the value with simple modifications ... Thats all :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<?php
  $arr = array(Div1, Div2);
  //give us the resulat of this please add to the post
  var_dump($arr);
  $array_to_object_json = json_encode($arr);
?>
```

We need to known what return this var_dump

```
<script>
  var global_json_from_php = <?php echo $array_to_object_json; ?>;
  $(document).ready(function(){
      console.log(global_json_from_php);
     for(i in global_json_form_php){
         $("."+global_json_from_php[i]).hide();
     }
  });
</script>
```